Multiple Y-Axes - Display to which Y-axis the series belongs
I am able to create multiple Y-Axes for multiple series that I plot on the graph -

As shown in the image, I can see two series plotted with multiple Y-Axes. But I'm not able to identify which series belongs to which Y-Axis just by looking at the graph. I can add the details of the Y-Axis in the legend, but that will be a workaround solution. Is there any way to do this without any manual workaround?

Add a background color to the axis labels, or the entire axis background and it should look readable

My question is not about readability. I want to make my viewers understand which bar belongs to which axis. That is, the blue bars belongs to left-axis and black bars belong to right-axis. As I said, manually I can add that detail in the legend, but I wanted to know if there is any way that the highchart can handle this.

the color of the axis matches the bar color end users will associate this by themselves

There are many ways you can improve readability. Some of them:

color the axis labels:

labels: {style: {color: 'color matching series color'}},

same way you can color axis title
you can move legend and increase the size of legend symbols to make it more visually illustrative
you can add annotation or render labels with SVG Renderer: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/renderer

Demo of first 2 steps: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v89r6jh4/

Thank you for your answer. But this also won't help me as in my application we have provided access for the users to update the font styles of the labels and the text. So, if I set the color, it still won't help as the client wants it to be user specific.
